# Cross-platform development using .Net Core Web API as the backend service, Angular and Ionic or React (ReactJS, React Native) and ElectronJS?

Tags: c#, reactjs, angular, react-native, ionic-framework

I would like to have an opinion from you guys at Stackoverflow, as I am struggling upon which front-end framework or library should I choose for my projects:

- 1 desktop application, 1 web application, 1 android application, 1 iOS application,

Prefer to have one-single-code-to-rule-them-all-for-the-frontend-framework.

as for the backend server side, I would choose .Net Core Web API.

What I have searching through the internet, I have found:

- I heard that Angular and Ionic makes a great combination for the development of Web, Desktop and Mobile, or Angular alone is enough as the front-end framework to build Web, Desktop and Mobile, while for the backend will communicate through Angular directive to the .Net Core Web API. What do you guys think about it?
- I also heard regarding ReactJS (Web), React Native (Mobile) and ElectronJS (Desktop), and have a question: is it one-single-code-base-to-rule-them-all-across-platforms (Web, Desktop and Mobile) , as well I heard that ReactNative have to build separate views for Android and iOS?

Which framework or library that is suitable for me to develop on?

I know that it is based on me to choose from, however I need to hear from you guys as I am a single developer who will works on those platforms (so I prefer one-code-to-rule-them-all)

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well everything here in the software development community is about needs!.

If you're going to be alone, should be good to do something with the most common framework to you.

Ionic can be used for web, [mobile](https://ionicframework.com/docs/deployment/play-store) and [desktop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/deployment/desktop-app).

Have fun coding!.